# ASP.NET WebApi Model Binding with Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container

I have an web application that is written in ASP.NET MVC 5 with Razor views that works perfectly. I have a set of model classes that expects an `ISomething` in the constructor, and that `ISomething` is injected there using Unity. Everything works very nice.

I have the model class like this:

```
public class SecurityRoleModel : PlainBaseModel
{
    #region Constructor
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SecurityRoleModel"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="encryptionLambdas">The encryption lambdas.</param>
    public SecurityRoleModel(IEncryptionLambdas encryptionLambdas)
    {
    }
    #endregion
}
```

In order to have the injection correctly working, I had to implement a custom `DefaultModelBinder` that takes care of the model constructor injection like this:

```
public class InjectableModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        if (modelType == typeof(PlainBaseModel) || modelType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(PlainBaseModel)))
            return DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(modelType);

        return base.CreateModel(controllerContext, bindingContext, modelType);
    }
}
```

Again, this is for the MVC part of the application, but now comes the ugly part: I have to implement a set of services (WebAPI) that deals with these models and I thought that I can do something similar to the MVC's `DefaultModelBinder` in WebAPI but it seems that is not as easy as I thought.

Now comes my question - though I've read (I think) a lot of posts regarding the implementation of custom `IModelBinder` (WebAPI), I cannot say that I found what I'm looking for; what I want is to find a way to not re-invent the wheel (to be read as "write a `IModelBinder` from scratch), I just want to have a place where the model class is instantiated and to have the possibility to put my code which gets the instance of the model class from the DI.

I hope I was clear enough. Thank you in advance.

Evdin

Comment: What about using a [TypeConvertor](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)? You should be able to access the dependency resolver from the convert factory method to new up your model.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you mean to override ConvertFrom or ConvertTo? I've tried with ConvertFrom but I receive only strings and I really don't want to re-create the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Though is not as broad as the MVC `DefaultModelBinder` and it covers only the situation when the serializer / deserializer is JSON.NET, the solution that I found for my issue is the following:

a) implement a custom version of `CustomCreationConverter<T>` from `Newtonsoft.Json.Converters` like this:

```
public class JsonPlainBaseModelCustomConverter<T> : CustomCreationConverter<T>
{
    public override T Create(Type objectType)
    {
        return (T)DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;

        return base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
    }
}
```

b) register the custom converter in the `WebApiConfig` class, `Register` method like this:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new JsonPlainBaseModelCustomConverter<PlainBaseModel>());
```

Though it might not be the optimal situation, it covers perfectly my issue.

If there is someone who knows a better solution, please let me know.

Thank you!